# when changing DataGridView combobox to Default Value, it throws exception

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a winform app which has one datagridview with combobox. Combobox is databound which displays model types. if i load previously saved data on gridview and try to select combobox first member which is NullValue (--Select--) it throws exception **Cannot set Column 'ModelTypeID' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.**. Full exception message is given below.

```
   at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value)
   at System.Data.DataRowView.SetColumnValue(DataColumn column, Object value)
   at System.Data.DataColumnPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object component,
   Object value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.PushValue
   (Int32 boundColumnIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
```

can anyone suggest me any workaround for this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this workaround mentioned [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/243da031-760d-4e7f-b09f-be4cfa5a6a4b/)

It involves subscribing to the column changing event for the DataTable bound

```
void dt_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Column == dt.Columns["myColumn"])
     {
         if (e.ProposedValue == null)
         {
              e.ProposedValue = DBNull.Value;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks pal, you saved mt life, i have been struggleing for this last 2 days.